# Mac Copy directory to any directory created in another directory

Tags: applescript, automator

So I have a directory which users copy folders into. I'd like to setup an automated way of copying a predefined directory into any folder added to the original root folder.

to explain what I mean:

I have a root folder `/Root`. Users can copy any folder they like into `/Root`. When they do, I'd like to copy the `/Addins/Images` folder into the `/Root/<user created folder>/` directory automatically. Result should be `/Root/<user created folder>/Images` - including all sub directories and files in the `/Addins/Images` folder.

I've heard automator might be able to do such a thing but have no idea how to use it. Any/all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Automator or Applescript, using action folder.

The Applescript bellow copy the folder Images (located in Addins) to any new folder added to MyRoot folder.

```
on adding folder items to myRoot after receiving FileList
set Addins to POSIX path of "Users:your_path:Addins:Images"
set Folderkind to "folder" -- value depends of your system language
tell application "Finder" -- loop on each item aded into the folder
repeat with one_Item in FileList
    if (kind of one_Item) is Folderkind then -- user has added a folder
        do shell script "cp -R " & (quoted form of Addins) & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of one_Item)
    end if
end repeat -- end loop on each added item
end tell
end adding folder items to
```

You must change the path to your folder Addins/Images (line 2).

Once compiled in Applescript Editor, you save this script in ~library/Scripts/Folder  Action Scripts.
Then, in Finder, select your folder "/root" and right click to add folder action on it (this folder action !).
Then, each time a folder will be added in this folder, the script will run.(because of "if" row 6, it will only run when a folder is added, not a simple file)

Warning: I am concerned about the /root folder you are using and I hope it is not the real root folder, but just an example. If not you will have authorization issues with real root folder.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes the 'root' folder is just an example. I'll test this out tonight and will report back. Thanks again.

Comment: I just tested your script. It works except it's copying the 'Images' folder to the root of the directory when I have the folder action running, I need to it to copy into the new folder inside the root folder..if that makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the first script by changing, in the do shell script line, the word 'myRoot' by the word  'one_item'. then Images folder is copied into the added folder.